# How to set d3 chart transition on chart load and transition when moving to next chart

Tags: d3.js

Two part question:

1. How to implement a transition time as initial area chart loads (i.e. it takes chart 1.5 seconds to load)?  For simplicity, use this area chart: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195
2. How to implement a transition between initial area chart and next line chart?  Again, let's use an mbostock creation: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

Comment: Both of these questions are quite fundamental and covered by numerous examples and questions here. Can you tell us what specifically you're struggling with?

Comment: Mostly the transition from initial area chart to the next line chart.  Basically how to do it -- what variables to set within the Javascript, etc.

Comment: Ok, something like this then? http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/11321854

Comment: Somewhat, but there are two different data sets for the area and line graph and there would be continuous transitioning from one graph to the other.

Comment: Well this should get you started :)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help -- do you have any quick thoughts about how you envision something like this to be set up?

Comment: Like in the example. To make it continous, you would need `setTimeout` or listen to the transition end event or something like this.